# Can someone explain what these laravel function do

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was going through my friend's laravel code, and saw some functions like `withPost` and others, here is the code

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $categorylist = Category::all();
        $tagfoot = Tag::all();
        $post = Post::find($id); 
        $popularposts= Post::selectRaw("posts.*, count('comments.id') as comments_count")->leftJoin('comments','comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')->groupBy('posts.id')->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')->take(6)->get();
        $prev = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();;
        $next = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        return view('posts.show')->withPost($post)->withTagfoot($tagfoot)->withCategorylist($categorylist)->withPrev($prev)->withNext($next)->withPopularposts($popularposts);
    }
```

What do the `withPost`, `withTagfoot`, `withCategorylist`, `withPrev`, `withNext`, `withPopularposts` functions actually do?

Comment: he is just passing those variable to view `posts.show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mentioned code sends values to the view `'posts.show'`.

Another way of sending value could be like the following. Here you can use the `compact` function of PHP to list the variables.

```php
return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'tagfoot', 'categorylist', 'prev', 'next', 'popularposts'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `with` keyword before a variable name to make a function is one of the ways you can pass that variable to views in Laravel. There are other ways and all are identical:

```
return view('posts.show')->withPost($post);
```

is just same as this:

```
return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
```